# Using Python to extract data from MS Access

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access

I need to extract a table from Access and print it in python. I have successfully connected the Access data base but I am not sure how to pull the table from Access and move it into a python data frame. I have inserted my code below.

```
odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (db_file, user, password)
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()
SQLCommand = 'select *from table1'

df = cur.execute(SQLCommand)
print(df)
conn.commit()
```

I get no errors but all this returns is

```
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0BCFF3A0>
```

Comment: try fetchall() command

Answer (score 2):

The fetchall() will retrieve the result

```
odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (db_file, user, password)
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()
SQLCommand = 'select * from table1'
cur.execute(SQLCommand)
df = cur.fetchall()
print(df)
```

You don't need to commit a select statement